# Applying for a position: Certificates and Supplements

Tags: application, faculty-application, application-cover-letter, soft-skills, certification

When applying for positions in academia (I think the question is valid for economy as well) I add several documents to my application: cover letter/motivational letter, CV, publication list, PhD Certificate, Diploma, employers' references. As a PhD student and as a post-doc I have visited several courses that train soft skills like conflict management and are certified. These courses are offered by the university and provide a certificat and a supplement.

For any application, should I attach both documents (certificate and supplement) or only the certificate?

All in all my application start to get quite bloated (around 16 to 22 pages).

Comment: Which country is this in?

Comment: I would say attached the "required" (specifically asked for) documents only! Regardless of the size of your application.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable (and I did this). However, sometimes the required documents are not specified.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because maybe I'm wrong, but I would think that if you have not been asked for explicit documentation, then you should just list these things in your CV.